# On algebraic topology of coset complexes without geometry

Tags: co.combinatorics, at.algebraic-topology, simplicial-complexes

I'm interested in understanding the algebraic topology of "coset complexes" from a "combinatorial" perspective (i.e., without relying on geometric realizations of the complexes). Given a finite group $G$ and subgroups $K_1,\ldots,K_r$, the "coset complex" $X$ is the $r$-partite complex whose vertices are a disjoint union of cosets $\bigsqcup_{i=1}^r G/K_i$ and with a maximal face for $g_1K_1,\ldots,g_rK_r$ iff these cosets have a nontrivial mutual intersection. (Thus, the maximal faces correspond to cosets $G/\bigcap_{i=1}^r K_i$.) Here is a theorem about the connectivity of these complexes:

**Theorem (e.g., ["Higher generation by subgroups"](https://pdf.sciencedirectassets.com/272332/1-s2.0-S0021869300X01615/1-s2.0-S0021869383711907/main.pdf.) by Abels and Holtz).** $X$ is simply connected iff $G$ is isomorphic to the free product of $K_1,\ldots,K_r$ amalgamated along their intersections, i.e., if $G \cong \langle \bigcup_{i=1}^r K_i \mid \bigcup_{i=1}^r \{\text{relations within }K_i\}\rangle$.

I am interested in the corollary of this theorem: If $G$ is isomorphic to this amalgamated product, then $X$ has vanishing first homology group over $\mathbb{F}_2$. Note that "vanishing first homology" has a purely combinatorial meaning: We can define boundary operators for $2$- and $1$-chains (e.g., for $f : X(1) \to \mathbb{F}_2$, $(\partial f)(v) = \sum_{e \in X(1) : e \ni v} f(e)$), and then vanishing first homology says that if $f : X(1) \to \mathbb{F}_2$ has $\partial f = 0$ (i.e., every vertex is incident to an even number of edges indicated by $f$) then there exists $g : X(2) \to \mathbb{F}_2$ where $f = \partial g$ (i.e., an edge indicated by $f$ iff it is incident to an odd number of triangles indicated by $g$).

I am looking for some pointers on how to prove the above fact as "combinatorially" as possible.

Here are a few specific questions:

(i) Is there any purely combinatorial meaning to what it means to contract a loop (or more generally perform a homotopy) within $X$? Purely combinatorial has no precise meaning, but I am hoping for understandable from a theoretical computer science background without algebraic topology :-) I am sure there is a good definition (indeed Garst's thesis, cited below, cites a "purely combinatorial definition of homotopy" due to Bundgaard, but Bundgaard's cited paper is in German!).

(ii) If you look at Ch. 6 of [Garst's thesis](https://www.proquest.com/docview/303007308) there is an *almost* combinatorial proof that the "amalgamated product" condition implies simply connectedness. Specifically, he first switches to the "nerve" complex $N$ of the coset complex $X$, whose vertices are the maximal faces of $X$, and whose maximal faces are intersections of maximal faces of $X$. He uses a "covering lemma" stating that this switch preserves simply connectedness. Now, it seems to be straightforward to show that (under the "amalgamated product" condition), every minimal loop in $N$ is contained entirely within one maximal face, and therefore that the homology is trivial (since the homology of a single simplex is trivial). But is there a "combinatorial" proof of this covering lemma, or some route which avoids it? (And also, is there a nice combinatorial proof that a single simplex has trivial homology? ;-) )

Thanks!

Aside: The "straightforward" proof seems to be that: Some sequence $g_1 (\bigcap_{i=1}^r K_i) \to \cdots \to g_k (\bigcap_{i=1}^r K_i) \to g_{k+1} (\bigcap_{i=1}^r K_i)$, $g_{k+1}=g_1$ forms a loop in the nerve complex iff $x_i := g_i^{-1} g_{i+1} \in K_{j_i}$ for some $j_i$ for each $i \in \{1,\ldots,k\}$. But $x_1 \cdots x_r = 1$. Thus we have a relation among elements in the subgroups and if the loop is 'minimal', I believe the assumption implies $x_i \in G_j$ for some $j$ for *all* $i$, and therefore the loop takes place within a single maximal face.

Comment: You may be interested in the notion of a van Kampen diagram (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_Kampen_diagram), which can be used to define simply connectedness in a purely combinatorial manner.

Comment: As far as combinatorial versions of homotopy equivalence: you might like collapsibility and its ilk.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collapse_(topology) .  This leads eventually towards discrete Morse theory, in which one alternatively collapses and "sets faces aside" (while remembering what they attach to).

Answer (score 2):

This result is known to me as "Tits Lemma" (I learned it as part of the theory of buildings) and he proved it in

> *Tits, Jacques*, Ensembles ordonnés, immeubles et sommes amalgamées, Bull. Soc. Math. Belg., Sér. A 38, 367-387 (1986). [ZBL0626.20027](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0626.20027)

which is in french. An english write up can be found in section 1.4 of

> *Ivanov, A. A.; Shpectorov, S. V.*, Geometry of sporadic groups. II: Representations and amalgams, Encyclopedia of Mathematics and Its Applications. 91. Cambridge: Cambridge University Press. xviii, 286 p. (2002). [ZBL0992.51006](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0992.51006).

Comment: Thanks! I assume the result you are referring to is 1.4.5 in that text ("The covering $\tilde{\tau}_{\mathcal{C}}$ is universal")? I'm not familiar with all this language but perhaps one can extract a self-contained proof? (At least, it's the most recent reference I have!)

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your question (ii):
So far as I know, proving the Nerve Lemma requires either a homotopy type argument, or a spectral sequence argument.  You can find the spectral sequence argument in Ken Brown's book "Cohomology of groups" (and surely other places).  Spectral sequences are not completely non-combinatorial, but I suspect this is not really what you are looking for.  The homotopy type argument can be reasonably nice via cellular collapses, and is sketched in exercise VII.4.4 of the same.  You might also like Anders Björner's "Topological Methods" handbook article, or Jonathan Barmak's article "On Quillen's Theorem A for posets".

As far as the homology of a simplex, there is a simple combinatorial argument that any cone over a finite simplicial complex is acyclic.  First, it is straightforward to show using either Mayer-Vietoris or relative homology that if a $(d-1)$-dimensional face $\sigma$ of $\Delta$ is contained in a unique $d$-dimensional facet $\tau$, then the homology of $\Delta$ and $\Delta \setminus \sigma$ agree.  Here, $\Delta \setminus \sigma$ removes both $\sigma$ and all containing faces (i.e., $\tau$), so I am modeling an uncomplicated simplicial collapse in homology.  I guess I am also (rightly!) claiming Mayer-Vietoris as combinatorics.  Now, you just note that whenever $\sigma$ is a facet of $\Delta$, then is is contained in a unique facet of $\operatorname{Cone} \Delta$; an easy induction now yields that the cone is acyclic.

If you want more background on the power and limitations of simplicial collapses / anticollapses, you might look at Marshall Cohen's book "A course on simple homotopy theory".

Comment: I believe there is a proof in J. Folkman's "The Homology Groups of a Lattice" (available on JSTOR https://www.jstor.org/stable/24901423) for the 'nerve lemma' which only uses Mayer-Vietoris and that barycentric subdivision preserves homology. If these are both 'combinatorial', then maybe that will be the most satisfying answer?

Comment: Either way, I will certainly take a look at the works you cite, and try to understand from a more 'modern' perspective.

Comment: Mayer-Vietoris tells you how to compute the homology of the union of two simplicial complexes.  That's pretty combinatorial!  The details do involve some linear algebra, as you'd expect for a linear algebraic invariant.